# Azure IoT hub message routing push with blob index tags

Tags: tags, azure-blob-storage, azure-iot-hub

I have a setup which consists of devices sending data to Azure cloud IoT Hub using message routing (to storage endpoints) which land up as blobs in a  container. The frequency of data push is high. On the other end, I want to be able to query my blob container to pull files based on specific dates.

I came across blob index tags which look like a promising solution to query and is supported by the Azure SDK for .net.

I was thinking to add tags to each blob ex: **processedDate**: **<dd/mm/yyyy>**, which would help me query on the same later.

I found out that while uploading the blobs manually it is possible to add the tags but not sure how to go about or where to configure the same in the message routing flow where blobs are created on the fly. So I am looking for a solution to add those tags in flight as they are being pushed on to the container.

Any help on this will be much appreciated.

Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

Presently, the Azure IoT Hub doesn't have a feature to populate a custom endpoint for instance headers, properties, tags, etc.

However, in your case such as a storage custom endpoint you can use an *EventGridTrigger* function to populate a blob based on your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will take a look at the EventGridTrigger solution as you have suggested. See if that works out.